# I have an ID of an object of an API, can i get and print that object?

Tags: javascript, function, api, vue.js, url

I made this simple application. There is a homepage where i print movies with an API, and if I click the movie it opens a page with the selected movie info. In the info page I made another Api call. I customized the url so when you click on more info, it returns the id of the object that contains the movie's info. So I made a function that takes the id from the url and confronts it with the one of the call API. if they match, the function returns true. But how am i supposed to get and print the movie info with this data? What would you do? Here is the code:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <div v-for="info in movieInfo"
            :key="info.id">

            {{info.id}}
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import axios from 'axios'

    export default {
        name: 'ViewComp',
        data() {
            return{
                movieInfo: [],
            }
        },
        mounted () {
            axios
                .get('https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/popular?api_key=###&language=it-IT&page=1&include_adult=false&region=IT')
                .then(response => {
                    this.movieInfo = response.data.results
                    // console.log(response.data.results)
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    console.log(error)
                    this.errored = true
                })
                .finally(() => this.loading = false)
        },
        methods: {
            confrontID(){
                var url = window.location.href;
                var idUrl = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
                var idMovie = this.info.id;

                if (idUrl === idMovie) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
        

    }

    
</script>

<style scoped lang="scss">
/*Inserire style componente*/
</style>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get rid of the "return true" on as it will return true if they match. Then instead return the movie info associated with the idUrl

```
if (idUrl === idMovie) {
   return idUrl;
 }
```

Then use that to reference the movie

Comment: Have you tried to use this answer? It shows how to display the data from the API call -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60241043/movie-searching-site-using-tmdb-and-axios-npm